# React is no longer show display from API after hiding API key and API url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Suggestions from "../Suggestions"


const API_URL = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news';

const API_KEY  = process.env;
console.log('getArticles');
console.log(API_KEY, API_URL);

class Home extends React.Component{

state = {
        articles : [],
        query: '',
    }




getArticles(){
    axios.get(`${API_URL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
            articles: data.data

        })
    })
 };


 handleInputChange = () => {
     this.setState ({
        query: this.home.value

     },
     () => {
         if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length >1) {
             if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
                 this.getArticles()
             }
         } else if (!this.state.query) {
         }
     })
 }

 render(){
    return (
        <>
        <form>
            <input
            placeholder= "Search for some shit"
            ref={input => this.search = input}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
            />

            <Suggestions results={this.state.articles} />
        </form>
        <div className="ui raised very padded text container segment">

        <ul>

            { this.state.articles.slice(0,1).map((article, index) => {
                return (<li key={index}>
                <h2>Title<br></br>{ article.title }</h2>
                <div> Author: { article.author }</div>
                <br></br>
                <p>{ article.content }</p>
                <a href={article.url}>{ article.url }</a>
               </li> )
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
   </>
    );
  }}


export default Home;
```

My console.log shows my url link along with the key. Maybe im writing getArticles wrong thats why the container not longer shows the API call. Before I hid the key/link it displayed correctly. To be honest im not fully sure what im doing what it comes to hiding keys in react. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you display correctly the `API_KEY` variable? `process.env` is an object with multiple keys so to access a specific key, you normally do `process.env.API_KEY` for instance or `const {API_KEY} = process.env`.

Comment: const API_KEY  = process.env.API_KEY;
console.log(process.env.API_KEY, API_URL); I sure did this is what I put from what you suggested still  undefined and still not displaying what im calling for in my container. My .env looks like this API_KEY=123456

Comment: One quick question...are you sure you have a `.env` file created with the `API_KEY` in it?